# Want to choose from: Node.js Meteor.js Ratchet RabbitMQ for Real-time WebChat(Forum)

Tags: node.js, websocket, rabbitmq, meteor, ratchet

I made some research before asking this question but I couldn't find a concrete answer for my situation.

I want to create WebChat with realtime sync to DB on server. (MySQL or MongoDB - all are OK)
But about syncing data there is few ways to do it:

1. PHP + websockets by Ratchet and my work is only to create a protocol by JSON to auth and messaging. Many docs, many tutorials.
   (i know that websockets didn't work in IE, but is no matter)
2. node.js + socket.io - there is same tech solution as 1. but in different language.
3. node.js + meteor.js (sockJS) - seems that guys did all work and I don't need to add any protocol functionality, just code the logic. But how about highload? How about documentation... very young framework.
4. Tornado + TornadIO2 (socket.io) + RabbitMQ

Can anybody compare RabbitMQ with meteor.js? By performance. Can anybody say which way is better?

I don't know about all frameworks, so if I have better options than those four, please tell me :)

Please give me your opinions. Thank you!

Comment: Why not combine node.js + socket.io with rabbitmq? It's feasible :P

Comment: Use sockjs and rabbitmq webstomp. Connects directly to your rabbitmq cluster from the client choosing the most suitable transport for the client.

Comment: There are a lot of solutions to this. This [realtime web tech guide](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide) provides some of the components you could use.

Answer (score 10):

I recommend **websocket** server based on **php**: [Ratchet](http://socketo.me).I use it, And this [link](http://www.cargomedia.ch/2012/11/05/Benchmarking-WebSocket-Servers.html) is **benchmarking** webSocket servers between **Ratchet** and **SockJS**.

Becuase you want to make webchat then need best performance and good cpu power.Ratchet has good solutions for handle message between client and server.It has broadcast send messaging and special send messaging for a group of clients,Also it has good control on server events for example mysql update by [ZMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) Libarary.Ratchet & ZMQ are on top of [Reactphp](http://reactphp.org/) Project

Also you can see WebRTC (Technology associated with WebSockets)that is another effort to enhance the communication capabilities of modern web browsers. WebRTC is peer-to-peer technology for the Web. The first applications for WebRTC are real-time voice and video chat. WebRTC is already a compelling new technology for media applications, and there are many available sample applications online that enable you to test this out with video and audio over the Web. Please check this [link](http://www.webrtc.org/)

Comment: I use Ratchet in my solution, however now I want to send binary data should I switch to Tornado or Twister kindly advise

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Tornado, so I don't know but this link: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/twisted.html may help you.You might want to ask a separate question tagged only tornado

Answer (score 1):

For realtime data web client synchronisation the solutions I know of are:

- [Meteor](http://meteor.com/)
- [Firebase](http://firebase.com)
- [Simperium](https://simperium.com/)
- [DerbyJS](http://derbyjs.com/)

Comment: Firebase is a whole BaaS, I cant see why you are mentioning it here. Isn't it out of the scope of this question?

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin - Firebase can be used as a standalone BaaS. But you can also use Firebase with other frameworks. The Firebase quickstart references the libraries for Clojure, Go, Java, PHP, Perl, Python and Ruby https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/quickstart.html As an application grows it's likely your going to need to write your own functionality that doesn't execute on the client. You'll may need the integrations for those scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I can only speak for the first three. My experience with websockets in general (that includes socket.io) has been sub-par, including sporadic disconnects and a convoluted connection system. With that said, however, it is very powerful and diverse. With websockets you can run a server or a client on nearly any platform. Socket.io limits this to a degree, but is really just a subset of websockets. Meteor however is a completely different ballgame. While it is confusing at first, I have been very impressed with how easy it is to build and deploy apps. It is powerful and flexible. Depending on how complicated the WebChat, either one would be a good option. If you are looking to do something simpler, I would go with socket.io. For more complex I would recommend meteor.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Meteor uses socket.io and websockets behind the scenes though, correct?

Comment: I don't believe so. I think they use AJAX and Comet, although I am not positive. Either way, the developer does not interface with websockets directly

Comment: Meteor use HTTP Long-Polling using [SockJS](https://github.com/sockjs). See http://cl.ly/image/0z031Z3H3g2F